# How can I change brightness of display on the zenbook ux325e?

Tags: intel-graphics, asus, brightness

I just bought an Asus Zenbook UX325E (with intel iris graphic) and installed ubuntu 20 on it but the screen brightness is at 100% and I can not change it, how to set display brightness or reduce it?

Comment: For brand new hardware the 20.04 release (there's no "Ubuntu 20") might not be the better choice.

Comment: There’s probably a keyboard shortcut - my Asus uses fn-f5 to dim and fn-f6 to increase brightness.